# how to join two query result and grouped it by a column

Tags: php, mysql, database, web

i have query joined by union and it give me desirable result separately in rows i want to join those two rows and add its values but i don't know how to do it the  query is

```
SELECT 
    `b`.`main_code`,
    `b`.`account_title`,
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN
            `a`.`type` = 'CP'
                AND `a`.`interactive_person` = '6'
                AND `a`.`date` BETWEEN '2018-02-12' AND '2018-07-31'
        THEN
            `a`.`balance`
        ELSE 0
    END) AS `credit`,
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN
            `a`.`type` = 'CR'
                AND `a`.`interactive_person` = '6'
                AND `a`.`date` BETWEEN '2018-02-12' AND '2018-07-31'
        THEN
            `a`.`balance`
        ELSE 0
    END) AS `debit`,
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN
            `a`.`type` = 'CR'
                AND `a`.`interactive_person` = '6'
                AND `a`.`date` BETWEEN '2018-02-12' AND '2018-07-31'
        THEN
            `a`.`balance`
        WHEN `a`.`type` = 'CP' THEN - 1 * `a`.`balance`
        ELSE 0
    END) AS `balance`
FROM
    `vouchers` AS `a`,
    `data` AS `b`
WHERE
    `a`.`interactive_person` = '6'
        AND `a`.`post_status` = 'yes'
        AND `a`.`interactive_person` = `b`.`main_code`
        AND `a`.`date` BETWEEN '2018-02-12' AND '2018-07-31' 
UNION SELECT 
    `b`.`main_code`,
    `b`.`account_title`,
    IFNULL(SUM(`a`.`debit`), 0) AS `debit`,
    IFNULL(SUM(`a`.`credit`), 0) AS `credit`,
    (`debit` - `credit`) AS `balance`
FROM
    `journal_vouchers` AS `a`,
    `data` AS `b`
WHERE
    `a`.`account_id` = '44'
        AND `a`.`date` BETWEEN '2018-02-12' AND '2018-07-31'
        AND `post_status` = 'yes'
        AND `cancel_status` = 'off'
        AND `a`.`account_id` = `b`.`account_code`
GROUP BY `b`.`main_code`;
```

the query is a bit complex let me explain it little: 
this query takes the result from 3 tables but main thing is that before union its take result from two table and after union two tables in which one table `data` interact with both. in short the result i get is

```
+-----------+---------------+--------+-------+---------+
| main_code | account_title | credit | debit | balance |
+-----------+---------------+--------+-------+---------+
|     6     |  cash account |  5200  |  520  |  -4680  |
+-----------+---------------+--------+-------+---------+
|     6     |  cash account |    0   |  200  |  -200   |
+-----------+---------------+--------+-------+---------+
```

i want the full query grouped by maincode but i dont know how do it 
i want result to be

```
6  | cash account | 5200 | 320 | -4880
```

Comment: You can wrap that select with another select, grouping by main_code, something like this: `SELECT main_code, account_title, SUM(credit), SUM(debit), SUM(balance) FROM (... the select you posted ...) tmp GROUP BY main_code;`

Comment: @JaviFernández OP said debit should be 320 but your query will return 720 correct?

Comment: use Nested queries

Comment: @JaviFernández i tried that already but the query is damn too complex and i dont know how to wrap it inside another select and it shows to me error but you wrote 'tmp' and i dont know what that mean but maybe thats the reason my way of using subquery wrong. can you explain what tmp mean ?

Comment: @Gaj Correct, my query will return 720. Maybe this can be useful for the OP if the values depend on each other, like `SELECT main_code, account_title, SUM(credit), SUM(credit)+SUM(balance), SUM(balance)...`

Comment: @ArsalanAfridi `tmp` is an alias for the result of the wrapped query, to use it as if it was a table. You can also write `AS tmp`.

Comment: @JaviFernández i used  mysql shows error but when i run the query executed unexpectedly and i manipulate the query a bit and got result the way i want ! in short your idea was helpful ! thanks